# Bash: call function from "bash -c"

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to get my bash function to call another function that uses `bash -c`. How do we make functions created earlier in the script persist between different bash sessions?

Current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

inner_function () {
    echo "$1"
    }
outer_function () {
    bash -c "echo one; inner_function 'two'"
    }
outer_function
```

Current output:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh 
one
bash: inner_function: command not found
```

Desired output:

```
one

two
```

Comment: upvote for well asked question

Comment: Why `bash -c` is necessary within a script that already is executed by bash, if you don't mind me asking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export it:

```
typeset -xf inner_function
```

Example:

```
#! /bin/bash
inner_function () { echo "$1"; }
outer_function () { bash -c "echo one; inner_function 'two'"; }
typeset -xf inner_function
outer_function
```

Other ways to write the exact same thing are `export -f inner_function` or `declare -fx inner_function`.

Notice that exported shell functions are **a)** a bash-only feature, not supported in other shells and **b)** still controversial, even after most of the bugs were fixed since [shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm confused about where to use the `typeset` command. Should it be outside the outer_function? inside the inner_function? inside the outer_function? I've tried several variations, nothing seems to work.

Comment: It should be before `bash -c ' ... inner_function ...` command is called. It adds it to the environment.

Comment: @user375954 this is currently implemented by creating an environment variable with a funny name and the source of the function as its value, which will be parsed by bash upon start up. Example: `bash -c 'foo(){ echo yup; }; export -f foo; printenv | grep -A1 foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

When I need the same function in several scripts, I put it in a side "library" script file and "source" that (`source the_lib_script` or `. the_lib_script`) in the scripts that need the function.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but I'm trying to keep the script self-contained.